# Different Format for Nomenclature or List of Abbreviations

Tags: acronyms, nomenclature, nomencl

For several types of scientific papers, it might be handy to have a separate page devoted on the nomenclature. With using this setup, the *nomencl*-package can be used. For one type of paper, however, I need to use the following setup:

---

**Abbreviations Used**

CEO, chief executive officer; CFO, chief financial officer; CMO, chief marketing officer (...)

---

Is there a way to have this automatically done (in alphabetic order)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you provide some more context, in the form of a small compilable document using `nomencl` that produces this abbreviation list, but in the wrong (i.e., default) format? The document should produce nothing else, so no content or packages that aren't necessary for the example. This would make it much easier to get started on answering your question, and it would also ensure that it works in your particular situation.

Answer (score 3):

If you have used the `nomencl` package already you should be familiar with its commands. The only thing you have to do is to add a suiting redefinition of the `thenomenclature` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\renewenvironment{thenomenclature}{%
  \section*{Abbreviations Used}
  \def\item[##1]{\noindent##1, \def\item[####1]{\unskip; ####1, }}%
}{}

\begin{document}

Text

\nomenclature{CEO}{chief executive officer}
\nomenclature{CFO}{chief financial officer}
\nomenclature{CMO}{chief marketing officer}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

And for the fun of it – here is how you could do the same with `acro`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\NewAcroTemplate[list]{para}{%
  \acroheading
  \acropreamble
  \newcommand\acrosep{\noindent\def\acrosep{; }}%
  \acronymsmapF{%
    \acrosep
    \acrowrite{short},
    \acrowrite {list}%
  }{\AcroRerun}%
  \par
}

\acsetup{
  use-id-as-short = true ,
  list/name = Abbreviations Used ,
  list/template = para
}

\DeclareAcronym{CEO}{long=chief executive officer}
\DeclareAcronym{CFO}{long=chief financial officer}
\DeclareAcronym{CMO}{long=chief marketing officer}

\begin{document}

\acuseall

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

The list looks the same.